# Can I preload another website that I own's page from a landing page?

Tags: html, jquery, shopify, preload

I have a landing page -> website I own that is shopify hosted setup. The shopify site loads slow and I want the webpage from shopify site to preload while customers are reading landing page, like in the background so when they click to go to shopify store page it is loaded and quick. Is this possible?

Comment: More information on what you're trying to do within Shopify would be helpful. However there is not any easy way to just load an entire document into memory in the browser and then just call on it when it's ready. Nor is it a particularly good idea.

You should be leveraging some form of caching of the Shopify data to help with load times. If the page content will be specific to the user you could create an AJAX request to sent the data to Shopify to be processed, cache it, and then load the cache if they click through which should speed up load times.

Knowing the exact problem would help

Comment: @jem  I am using a Shopify landing page creator [gempages] and want to preload from presell WordPress landing page. In theory, if full gempages landing page is preloaded on WordPress presell page then accessing it would take split seconds after clicking presell page button. I will 100% look into the caching solution mentioned thanks for answer

Comment: I'm not sure this is preloading but you could put the slow loading page in an 'iframe' on the main page.  Then change the button code to show the 'iframe'.

Comment: *"Is this possible?"*. Not in any practical way

Answer (score 0):

If your Shopify site is loading slow, there can only be one explanation. You are doing it wrong, using bad Apps and probably running bad Javascript. Try fixing your broken Shopify as a priority rather than trying to paper over the fact that it is slow. A lot of good Shopify stores get 80+ in Lighthouse reviews with no trouble. That being said, I know lots of very successful stores that also run 20/100 on Lighthouse, so being slow is not hurting them either.

Comment: Understood friend, I am using a Shopify landing page creator [gempages] and it loads faster than shopify site but if it can be loaded faster through preload - why not ygm. I am just wondering if this is possible in way listed as with customer every second count

Comment: As I mentioned, there is zero need to generate a fake landing page. Just make your Shopify landing page normal, and it'll be as fast.